# How can i write and read many urls in on file in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, io

I wrote this code in python 2.7 for writing the urls in textfile

```
f = io.open('./pages/page%s' % str(self.pageNumber), 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(unicode(response.url))
f.close()
self.pageNumber = self.pageNumber + 1
```

instead of many pages, how can i have all **response.url** in one file (line by line) and after that how can i read this url line by line?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @MattDMo thanks, i read it and i wrote my code by that, but i don't know how to put  all the results in one file without overwriting, someting like >> in shell

Comment: i use a for loop, but at last i have just the last url, i don't know how not overwrite to my file and have all my urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question:

i should use **a** instead of **w**